# Unexpected token error:awk when ran with sh var

Tags: linux, awk, sh

I have a file that contain the data format:
myfile:

```
ABC7
{
0198cc998
};
FF48
{
01988899f
};
```

I need to make a sh function with paramater id_data and return data like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
get_data()
{
    cmd="awk '/$1/{getline; getline; print}' $2"
    echo $cmd
    export result=`$cmd`
}

get_data "ABC7" "myfile"
echo $result
```

When I execute the script I get this error:

```
awk '/ABC7/{getline; getline; print}' myfile 
# when I copy this line and I execute it manually it works
awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token
```

how to run awk composed in shell variables?

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do. You are showing a very unefficient piece of code which is not very clear what is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need all this wrapping of the awk script to pass an argument.  There is a `-v` option for this.

```
 $ var=ABC7; awk -v key="$var" -v RS="};" '$1~key{print $3}' data

 0198cc998
```